# Select Pandas rows based on list index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe df`:

```
20060930  10.103       NaN     10.103   7.981
20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915  12.686
20070331   3.196       NaN      3.196   2.710
20070630   7.907       NaN      7.907   6.459
```

Then I want to select rows with certain sequence numbers which indicated in a list, suppose here is [1,3], then left:

```
20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915  12.686
20070630   7.907       NaN      7.907   6.459
```

How or what function can do that?

Answer (score 245):

Use `.iloc` for integer based indexing and `.loc` for label based indexing. See below example:

```
ind_list = [1, 3]
df.iloc[ind_list]
```

Comment: This is now deprecated, .iloc should be used for positional indexing

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use `df.iloc[[1,3],:]`

Comment: The solution in the update doesn't work either, I have the latest working solution as of March 2021 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579467/14022582)

Comment: This will work as long as you can guarantee `ind_list` is a subset of `df.index`. If `ind_list` contains even a single element that doesn't exist in `df.index`, Pandas will raise a keyerror. If you can't guarantee that, use `isin` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 151):

you can also use iloc:

```
df.iloc[[1,3],:]
```

This will not work if the indexes in your dataframe do not correspond to the order of the rows due to prior computations. In that case use:

```
df.index.isin([1,3])
```

... as suggested in other responses.

Answer (score 120):

Another way (although it is a longer code) but it is faster than the above codes. Check it using %timeit function:

```
df[df.index.isin([1,3])]
```

PS: You figure out the reason

[image]

Comment: use `df.index.get_level_values(0).isin` for multiindex

Comment: Your comparison is invalid, because it should compare with `df.iloc` instead of `df.loc`.

Answer (score 27):

If `index_list` contains your desired indices, you can get the dataframe with the desired rows by doing

```
index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df.loc[df.index[index_list]]
```

This is based on the latest [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing) as of March 2021.

Comment: This is a great answer. The advantage of this method is that you can use the full power of df.loc. For example you can select the column you want with df.loc[df.index[index_list], "my_column"] and even set values with df.loc[df.index[index_list], "my_column"] = "my_value"

Answer (score 6):

For large datasets, it is memory efficient to read only selected rows via the `skiprows` parameter.

**Example**

```
pred = lambda x: x not in [1, 3]
pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=pred, index_col=0, names=...)
```

This will now return a DataFrame from a file that skips all rows except 1 and 3.

---

**Details**

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> `skiprows` : list-like or integer or callable, default `None`
>
> ...
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x in [0, 2]`

This feature works in version pandas 0.20.0+.  See also the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10882) and a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677183/quickly-sampling-large-number-of-rows-from-large-dataframes-in-python/39677807#39677807).

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of solving this problem, and the ones listed above are the most commonly used ways of achieving the solution. I want to add two more ways, just in case someone is looking for an alternative.

```
index_list = [1,3]

df.take(pos)

#or

df.query('index in @index_list')
```

Comment: this is the correct answer if you have say a named index like: `pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0, 6, 10], 'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], 'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8, 3, 0], 'do_I_like_it': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]}, index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish', 'dragonfly', 'limulus'])`

Comment: @user27221 could you please take your DataFrame, transpose it, and then explain me how to select `num_legs` based on `num_wings == 0` and `do_I_like_it == 1`?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is to filter your dataframe by index. The best way to do that in pandas at the moment is the following:

**Single Index**

```
desired_index_list = [1,3]
df[df.index.isin(desired_index_list)]
```

**Multiindex**

```
desired_index_list = [1,3]
index_level_to_filter = 0
df[df.index.get_level_values(index_level_to_filter).isin(desired_index_list)]
```

Answer (score 3):

**To get a new DataFrame from filtered indexes:**

For my problem, I needed a new dataframe from the indexes. I found a straight-forward way to do this:

```
iloc_list=[1,2,4,8]
df_new = df.filter(items = iloc_list , axis=0)
```

You can also filter columns using this. Please see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for details.