# Random sampling and Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, cr_df, which shows the rate at which ID1 converts to ID2

```
   ID1 ID2 Conversion Rate
0  1     A      0.046562
1  1     B      0.315975
2  1     C      0.577998
3  1     D      0.059465
4  2     A      0.6
5  2     B      0.4
```

Then I have another dataframe, raw_df, in the format of ID1 such as:

```
   ID1 Value
0  1     100  
1  2     200
```

My goal is to output a dataframe final_df, in the ID2 format that looks something like:

```
   ID2 Value
0  C     100  
1  A     200
```

Where the mapping from ID1 consists of selecting a random value between 0 and 1 and picking the ID2 based off the conversion rates.

How can I achieve this in pandas? (Do I need to use .apply?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID1': [1]*4+[2]*2, 'ID2':list('ABCDAB'), 
    'Conversion Rate': [0.046562, 0.315975, 0.577998, 0.059465, 0.6, 0.4]})
raw_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': [1,2], 'Value':[100, 200]})
```

you could define a function `random_id2`:

```
def random_id2(x):
    return np.random.choice(x['ID2'], p=x['Conversion Rate'].values)
```

and use `groupby/apply`:

```
id2 = df.groupby(['ID1']).apply(random_id2)
```

to obtain the Series

```
ID1
1    C
2    A
dtype: object
```

You could then build `final_df` by mapping `raw_df['ID1']` values to `id2` values:

```
final_df = raw_df.copy()
final_df['ID1'] = final_df['ID1'].map(id2)
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={'ID1': 'ID2'})
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID1': [1]*4+[2]*2, 'ID2':list('ABCDAB'), 
    'Conversion Rate': [0.046562, 0.315975, 0.577998, 0.059465, 0.6, 0.4]})
raw_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': [1,2], 'Value':[100, 200]})

def random_id2(x):
    return np.random.choice(x['ID2'], p=x['Conversion Rate'].values)

id2 = df.groupby(['ID1']).apply(random_id2)

final_df = raw_df.copy()
final_df['ID1'] = final_df['ID1'].map(id2)
final_df = final_df.rename(columns={'ID1': 'ID2'})

print(final_df)
```

yields

```
  ID2  Value
0   C    100
1   A    200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a combination of the following:

- To make a weighted random choice of the rows, use the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803135/weighted-choice-short-and-simple); specifically, make a weighted selection of `range(len(df))` with the weights given by `df[Conversion Rate]`.
- To select the rows with the given indices, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155718/select-pandas-rows-based-on-list-index).
- To join the resulting dataframe with the second one, use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)