# Quickly sampling large number of rows from large dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling, bigdata

I have a very large dataframe (about 1.1M rows) and I am trying to sample it.

I have a list of indexes (about 70,000 indexes) that I want to select from the entire dataframe.

This is what Ive tried so far but all these methods are taking way too much time:

Method 1 - Using pandas :

```
sample = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", index_col = 0).reset_index()
sample = sample[sample['Id'].isin(sample_index_array)]
```

Method 2 :

I tried to write all the sampled lines to another csv.

```
f = open("data.csv",'r')

out  = open("sampled_date.csv", 'w')
out.write(f.readline())

while 1:
    total += 1
    line = f.readline().strip()

    if line =='':
        break
    arr = line.split(",")

    if (int(arr[0]) in sample_index_array):
        out.write(",".join(e for e in (line)))
```

Can anyone please suggest a better method? Or how I can modify this to make it faster?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand you right, you can probably turn your indicies into a pandas Index object.  Then feed the object into the DataFrame to slice it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have your data, so here is an example with two options:

1. *after reading*: use a pandas `Index` object to select a subset via the `.iloc` [selection method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)
2. *while reading*: a predicate with the [`skiprows` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

**Given**

A collection of indices and a (large) sample `DataFrame` written to `test.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


indices = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 67, 78, 900, 2176, 78776]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000000, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
df.to_csv("test.csv", header=False)
df.info()
```

Output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    1000000 non-null int32
B    1000000 non-null int32
C    1000000 non-null int32
D    1000000 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(4)
memory usage: 15.3 MB
```

**Code**

*Option 1 - after reading*

Convert a sample list of indices to an `Index` object and slice the loaded `DataFrame`:

```
idxs = pd.Index(indices)   
subset = df.iloc[idxs, :]
print(subset)
```

The [`.iat` and `.at` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat) are even faster, but require scalar indices.

---

*Option 2 - while reading* (Recommended)

We can write a predicate that keeps selected indices as the file is being read (more efficient):

```
pred = lambda x: x not in indices
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skiprows=pred, index_col=0, names="ABCD")
print(data)
```

See also the [issue that led to extending `skiprows`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10882).

---

**Results**

The same output is produced from the latter options:

```
        A   B   C   D
1      74  95  28   4
2      87   3  49  94
3      53  54  34  97
10     58  41  48  15
20     86  20  92  11
30     36  59  22   5
67     49  23  86  63
78     98  63  60  75
900    26  11  71  85
2176   12  73  58  91
78776  42  30  97  96
```

Comment: Thanks! This should work!
Just out of curiosity, is there a way to slice these rows while reading the data?

Comment: Okay. Ill try skiprows. Thanks!