# Pandas: Selecting rows to create new dataframe using the index

Tags: python, pandas, extract, rows

Simple question. I have a dataframe that looks like this (call if `df1`):

```
Country 2016 2017 2018
USA 1 2 3 
CAN 4 5 6
MEX 7 5 6
ARG 9 3 5 
GBR 5 8 2
```

I have a variable called `countries` which looks like this: `countries=['USA','MEX','GBR']`. How can I make a new dataframe (call it `df2`) which selects only the rows mentioned in `countries`?

I can select rows manually, or several of them if they are in a block (say USA to MEX), but I don't know how to do it if the order is random. A loop could do it, (see below) but that only saves the last country in the loop!

```
for country in countries:
    df2 = df1.loc[country:country,:].copy()
```

PS. I'm sure this is a duplicate! But I've spent a good hour searching for the answer with no success.

Comment: `df2 = df1.loc[countries]` should works

Comment: If Country is a column, not the name of the index you need `df1[df1['Country'].isin(countries)]`

Comment: OMG - I knew it was simple. So simple that no one has probably asked it before.

Comment: Country is the index. I just tried @jezrael solution and it worked. Feel like a bit of a newb! (well I am for python)

Comment: @ayhan - csn you check if is dupe for this? Because now it is marked bad...

Comment: @jezrael I've reopened it.

Comment: Hmmm, it is dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19155718/2901002

Comment: @ahyan  yep nice! works for index too with the alternative: `df2 = df1[df1.index.isin(countries)]`